# Overriding/removing inline !important

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site using htmlcommentbox.com's comment system. It seems to use inline !importants to make a link to the site stay there. This is the code I'm using from them:

`<!-- begin htmlcommentbox.com -->
 <div id="HCB_comment_box">Loading comments...</div>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="htmlcommentbox.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" id="hcb"> /*<!--*/ if(!window.hcb_user){hcb_user={};} (function(){var s=document.createElement("script"), l=(hcb_user.PAGE || ""+window.location), h="//www.htmlcommentbox.com";s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");s.setAttribute("src", h+"/jread?page="+encodeURIComponent(l).replace("+","%2B")+"&mod=%241%24wq1rdBcg%247.bGleVasiPPOiHF49trb0"+"&opts=342&num=10");if (typeof s!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);})(); /*-->*/ </script>
<!-- end htmlcommentbox.com -->`

My CSS is:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
p {
    color: #FFF;
}
a {
    color: #FFF;
}
span,
div a {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I will include more if necessary. Can I remove the link to their site?

Comment: do you have access to that part of the code or is it remote? what HTML code does it render?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply select the element and remove the `style` attribute:

```
document.querySelector('.home-desc + a').removeAttribute('style');
```

..then you can use the following CSS to hide it:

```
.home-desc + a,
.home-desc {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqaxuwco/)

Alternatively, since all you are doing is hiding the elements, you could just remove them entirely.

You could also avoid JS completely and set the `opacity` to `0` and add `pointer-events: none`. This will essentially hide the element(s).

```
.home-desc + a,
.home-desc {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**Example demonstrating this**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqgw34wo/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to remove the link from the DOM after the script has been executed, then you do not need to remove or override the !important:

```
document.getElementById('HCB_comment_box').addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    var desc = document.querySelector('#HCB_comment_box .home-desc');
    var link = document.querySelector('#HCB_comment_box .home-desc').nextSibling;
    var parent = desc.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(desc);
    parent.removeChild(link);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/14nq38fo/)